# How to use inline svg's in Blazor wasm .NET 5

Tags: svg, blazor

My Blazor wasm project is targeting the .NET 5.0 runtime. I've got .NET SDK 5.0.200 and .NET Runtime 5.0.2 installed.

According to Zaneris on this Github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18271#issuecomment-745580813), inline svg's can be used like this in Blazor:

```
<div>
   <svg> <use xlink:href="images/test.svg#test-logo" /> </svg>
</div>
```

[image: photo-wwwroot]

However, I can only get it to work like this:

```
         <div>
            <svg>
                <symbol id="test-logo" viewBox="0 0 255.905 185.056">
                    <g id="Group_284" data-name="Group 284" transform="translate(-65.569 -74.438)">
                        ...
                    </g>
                </symbol>
                <use xlink:href="#test-logo" />
            </svg>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to link the svg file in the head tag? If so, what do I set the "rel" to?

I would love to be able to reference the symbol ID straight from the svg file in wwwroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I made a sample file and tested the technique you mentioned in your OP, and was able to display two symbols from a single file by #referencing them.  So the technique seems not to be the problem.

However, they were upside down from the original.  My understanding was that you could just use a symbol and it would work, but maybe it needs a little more tinkering somehow, with regard to setting the viewboxes properly?

--edit--
According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href), "xlink:href" is now obsolete.  So there's a possibility that at some point in the future, client sites will break.  I doubt it will be soon because it seems to be a VERY new update, but something to consider.

Comment: Oh interesting. I took that svg file out of a Vue.js project and put it in Blazor to reference it the same way. So you think it could be rendering differently in Blazor? I got nothing at all. I'll try some other symbols and see if I can get anything. Did you have to link the file in the head tag?

Comment: Found the problem. In Vue.js, the svg file was being used without a svg tag in the file. It was full of symbol tags only. In Blazor, I had to wrap the symbol tags in an svg tag and it worked! I was able to use it like in my OP. No head link required. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: I cannot upvote, since I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: Haha no problem.  Although I've gotten pretty good at my way of doing things, I honestly didn't know about symbols or about referencing symbols in a file like that.  Now I definitely need to make a big file of icons.  Please read my updated comment to my last answer though, because there may be a minor problem with this method in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to sell you on the idea of treating .svg code like any other markup and putting it into Razor components.  This way, you can put it inline anywhere you want, and control variables like you would with any other razor control:

Here's an .svg saved from illustrator: **(sample.svg)**

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.3.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 16.2917 24.9155)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="12px">Lorem ipsum</tspan></text>
    <circle fill="#EC008C" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="50" cy="58.8" r="15.3" />
</svg>
```

Here's a razor page I made from it, **(SampleSVG.razor)**.  Note the variables **@Text** and **@fill**.  I can put it anywhere I want like any other component: `<SampleSVG />`

```
@page "/svgsample"


Change Text: <input @bind="@Text" /><button @onclick="DoCoolStuff">Go Crazy!</button>
<div style="width:50%; height:auto">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" style="stroke-width: 0px; background-color: #000000;" xml:space="preserve">
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 16.2917 24.9155)">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" fill="orange" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="12px">@Text</tspan>
        </text>
        <circle fill="@fill" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="50" cy="58.8" r="15.3" />
    </svg>
</div>


@code {
    string Text = "Start Text";
    string fill = "#EC008C";
    Random random = new Random();

    async Task DoCoolStuff()
    {
        for (int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        {
            fill = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
            StateHasChanged();
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
    }
}
```

Pro-tip: since the button handler is async, if you click it over and over really fast, you can change the circle's color more than 5x / second.  DISCO! (and possible seizure warning. . . )

Comment: As an aside, just so you know it's not only working on one browser: https://caniuse.com/svg-html5

Comment: That could work. How would you handle a situation where multiple symbols are in 1 file and you need to select only 1 for rendering? Would you make something like an enum property on the razor component and conditionally show symbols, or how would you pull it off?

Comment: This is one of those cases where there are about a hundred ways to skin a cat.  It depends on how many symbols you have, and whether it's important to you to keep them in their original files, and whether you actually care about any of the shenanigans I just showed (you might not).

Comment: I understand. The reason I originally asked for the inline svg by symbol ID is because we have large svg files with tons of symbols in them. They are used as icons essentially. I really don't want one per file and need to pull them as needed in any component. JavaScript SPA's can do that and I need to be competitive with Blazor if I have any chance of selling Blazor.